# How to fill between two Line2D.Double?

Tags: java, graphics, shapes

Hi I'm trying to create ***heart*** shape for my application and 
I could do the hollow one and it's working good, now I need to draw it with filled method but it's created by two Arc2D.Double and two Line2D.Double so because of this just the Arc's filling and two lines not.I've tried to add these two lines in two different 'Area' and add these two areas in one but also not worked.

There is a any way to do this (filling between two lines)?Thanks advance.

My codes : **Class Heart**

```
`public class HeartShape {

    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes;
    public HeartShape() {

    }

    public ArrayList<Shape> Heart(double x, double y, double HEART_RADIUS) {
        shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        double r = HEART_RADIUS;
        double root2 = Math.sqrt(2);
        double cx = x;
        double cy = y;
        double dx = r / root2;
        double heights = 3 * dx + r;
        double top = cy - heights / 2;
        double bottom = cy + heights / 2;
        Shape s = new Arc2D.Double(cx - dx - r, top, 2 * r, 2 * r, 45, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);
        shapes.add(s);
        s = new Arc2D.Double(cx + dx - r, top, 2 * r, 2 * r, -45, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);
        shapes.add(s);
        s = new Line2D.Double(cx, bottom, cx - 2 * dx, bottom - 2 * dx);
        shapes.add(s);
        s = new Line2D.Double(cx, bottom, cx + 2 * dx, bottom - 2 * dx);
        shapes.add(s);
        if (shapes != null) {
            return shapes;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void drawHeart(Graphics2D g2d, boolean isFilled) {

        if (isFilled == true) {
                    shapes.forEach((ss) -> {
                        g2d.fill(ss);
                    });
        } else {
                    shapes.forEach((ss) -> {
                        g2d.draw(ss);
                    });
        }

    }`
```

And ***DrawinTest*** :

```
public class DrawinTest extends JPanel{
private int HEART_RADIUS;
private Point startpoint;
private int x, y, width, height;
private HeartShape heartShape = new HeartShape();
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DrawinTest();
}

public DrawinTest() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test Area");
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 1));
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseListener());
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    f.setContentPane(this);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.pack();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

    if(heartShape != null) {
        heartShape.Heart(x, y, HEART_RADIUS);
        heartShape.drawHeart(g2d, false);

    }
   g2d.dispose();
}

class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        startpoint = new Point(e.getPoint());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x = Math.min(startpoint.x, e.getX());
        y = Math.min(startpoint.y, e.getY());
        width = Math.abs(startpoint.x - e.getX());
        height = Math.abs(startpoint.y - e.getY());
        HEART_RADIUS = Math.min(width, height);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

   }
}
```

So far its looking like this :

[image: Empty][image: Filled]

Comment: Use the `Shape` API to generate a "closed" shape - [As a conceptual example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041397/how-to-paint-a-group-of-quadcurves-using-java-graphics2d/30042600#30042600)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for fast replay, can you show me how to do this please? Because my brains are tired of dealing with it.

Comment: Yeah, I added an example link to the previous comment ;)

Comment: Oh, just notice, you've almost got it. I've updated your code with an example which combines it with a `Path2D` to generate a single shape

Comment: I want to know why my question down voted?There is a any wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Shape`s API has a number of really interesting APIs, one of my favorites is `Path2D`

Basically, what it allows you to do is append other `Shape`s, making it very useful in this situation.

```
public class HeartShape {

    private Shape shape;

    public HeartShape() {

    }

    public Shape Heart(double x, double y, double HEART_RADIUS) {
        double r = HEART_RADIUS;
        double root2 = Math.sqrt(2);
        double cx = x;
        double cy = y;
        double dx = r / root2;
        double heights = 3 * dx + r;
        double top = cy - heights / 2;
        double bottom = cy + heights / 2;

        Path2D base = new Path2D.Double();
        Shape s = new Arc2D.Double(cx - dx - r, top, 2 * r, 2 * r, 45, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);
        base.append(s, false);
        s = new Line2D.Double(cx, bottom, cx - 2 * dx, bottom - 2 * dx);
        base.append(s, true);
        s = new Line2D.Double(cx, bottom, cx + 2 * dx, bottom - 2 * dx);
        base.append(s, true);
        s = new Arc2D.Double(cx + dx - r, top, 2 * r, 2 * r, -45, 180, Arc2D.OPEN);
        base.append(s, true);

        base.closePath();

        shape = base;

        return base;
    }

    public void drawHeart(Graphics2D g2d, boolean isFilled) {
        System.out.println("...");
        if (isFilled) {
            g2d.fill(shape);
        } else {
            g2d.draw(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041397/how-to-paint-a-group-of-quadcurves-using-java-graphics2d/30042600#30042600), you don't need to re-create the shape when you want to change it's size, you can simply create an instance of it at a "default" size and use a `AffineTransform` to resize it, much easier ;)

Comment: Perfect  answer and +1 for you.Thank you so much.

Comment: @CoderACJHP Glad it could help ;)

Comment: Could some please explain to me why this answer would attract a downvote?  I what ways does it not answer the question?  In what ways would it be improved? Seen as the question has not received any new downvotes, I assume you don't find issue with the question, since no other answers have been downvoted or new answers added, I assume you're only taking issue with me personally ... which is a shame

Answer (score 1):

I think that instead of using an arrayList of shapes you should use a GenericPath and append each individual shape to it with `GenericPath.append()`. One you're done add the pieces of the heart use `GenericPath.closePath()` to make it a close it up so that it can be filled. Then you should be able to use the new GenericPath object as the path to be drawn with `g2d.draw`